# How to properly handle JwtException.?

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

when the token expires I get such an error

```
io.jsonwebtoken.JwtException: JWT expired at 2020-09-18T19:08:08Z. Current time: 2020-09-22T20:26:51Z, a difference of 350323563 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.
```

I created a class that implements AuthenticationEntryPoint

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {


    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                         AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = ErrorDetails.builder()
                .details(String.valueOf(e.getClass()))
                .message("JWT has expired")
                .timestamp(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
                        .format(LocalDateTime.now()))
                .build();
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
        httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(mapper.writeValueAsString(errorDetails));
    }
```

in Postman I get

```
{
    "timestamp": "09-22-2020 20:26:51",
    "message": "JWT has expired",
    "details": "class org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException"
}
```

configure method form SecurityConfig

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), secret),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/credit/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().denyAll();
        http
                .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Content-Type", "application/json"));
    }
```

Someone can advise me on how to properly handle the exception that I get in the IDE.
**Solution**
in JwtAuthorizationFilter

```
catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            request.setAttribute("expired", e.getMessage());
        }
```

in CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint

```
if(httpServletRequest.getAttribute("expired") != null){
            errorDetails.setMessage(String.valueOf(httpServletRequest.getAttribute("expired")));
        }
```

Comment: post your code where you have created jwt token. It's because of the expiration time.

Comment: @SurajGautam does not yet create a new token after it expires. I do not know if I will do it because I check the token in ApiGateway and create the token in another service

Comment: if the token can be automatically renewed you should catch the exception and renew the token for the user. Otherwise, just return the login page for the user to re-login.

Comment: I understand that, but for now I would like to know how to handle such an error

Comment: Okay. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Security 5.1+ has [built-in support for JWTs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture).

Instead of wiring your own custom filter, you can configure Spring Security to look for JWTs:

```java
http
    // ...
    .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
        .authenticationEntryPoint(myCustomEntryPoint)
        .jwt()
    )
    // ... no need for a custom filter
```

Since you have a custom way to process the JWT, you can publish [your own implementation of `JwtDecoder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-decoder-bean):

```
@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return (encodedJwt) -> {
        // verify the JWT
    }
}
```

Spring Security's bearer token filter will call your `AuthenticationEntryPoint` at the appropriate time as well as reduce some of your app's customization.

Comment: For others; see https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo for a working example.

Comment: Where can we set a custom exception handling with this solution, for example if the JWT is expired I want to return a error message.

Comment: In the custom `JwtDecoder`, throw a `JwtException`. You can subclass it to your custom needs. It will get wrapped in an an `OAuth2AuthenticaitonException` that you can call `getCause` on to get your custom exception.

Answer (score 2):

//    You can simply surround your Filter class with try block and catch this // exception

```
 catch (Exception exception){
                log.error("Error logging in : {} ", exception.getMessage());
                response.setHeader("error",exception.getMessage());
                response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());
                Map<String,String > error = new HashMap<>();
                error.put("error_message",exception.getMessage());
                response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(),error);
            }
```

//    and then in your util class where you  are validating your token catch //this

```
 public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails, HttpServletRequest request)  {
        try {
            final String username = extractUsername(token);
            log.info("Username " + username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()));
            return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException expiredJwtException) {
            log.info("Utils :: validateToke :: token Exception -> expired!");
            request.setAttribute("expired",expiredJwtException.getMessage());
            throw new ExpiredJwtException(expiredJwtException.getHeader(), expiredJwtException.getClaims(), "Expired JWT token");
```

//    You will get your desired response in after following these steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we can catch the JwtException (io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException).

Key Parts are:

- configure the `JWTFilter` before `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`
- parse the JWT Token and catch `ExpiredJwtException`
- wrap `ExpiredJwtException` in one of the implementation of `AuthenticationException` and rethrow so that it will be handled in your `CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint`. Note that `org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter#handleSpringSecurityException` delegates to `AuthenticationEntryPoint` only for `AuthenticationException` and `AccessDeniedException`

**The JWTFilter**

```
@Slf4j
public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);

        try {
            Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key).build()
                    .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();

            //everything is valid !!, let's login
            Authentication authentication = getAuthentication(claims);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            log.error("Expired JWT token.", e);
            //HANDLE IT HERE::::: wrap ExpiredJwtException in AuthenticationException and rethrow Exception
           throw new CredentialsExpiredException("Expired jwt credentials ", e);

        } catch (OtherExceptions e) {
            log.info("JWT token compact of handler are invalid.");
            log.trace("JWT token compact of handler are invalid trace: ", e);
        }

        //finally filter it through
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }


}
```

Comment: thx, but I dont understand what means "wrap ExpiredJwtException in AuthenticationException"

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-wrapping.html

Comment: I still can't do it.` catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException(e.getMessage());
            //throw new CustomAuthenticationException(e.getMessage());

        }catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
        } `and I keep getting the same log

Comment: is it possible for you to share your project?

Comment: You will need to have  `} catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            throw new CredentialsExpiredException("Expired jwt credentials ", e);
        }` at com.creditApp.security.JwtAuthorizationFilter#getAuthentication

Comment: adding this code raises an exception in the console and in postman I get "". Using request.setAttribute () is better because there is no error in the console and in postman I get more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some users may still encounter issues with JWT authentication in 2023 and beyound. I faced a similar problem and found a workaround that might be helpful to others.

In my project, I had a `JwtAuthenticationFilter`, and I'd like to draw your attention to a Bean called `HandlerExceptionResolver`. By using the `handlerExceptionResolver`, we can handle most JWT exceptions gracefully. However, depending on the specific JSON error response we want to send back to our users, we can create a custom `ExceptionHandler` class.

Here's an example of how you can structure your code:

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthenticationFilter.class);
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver;
    private static  final String HEADER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
    private static final String REQUEST_HEADER = "Authorization";
    private final JwtService jwtService;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(UserRepository userRepository, @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver, JwtService jwtService) {

        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.handlerExceptionResolver = handlerExceptionResolver;
        this.jwtService = jwtService;

    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NotNull HttpServletRequest request, @NotNull HttpServletResponse response, @NotNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authenticationHeader = request.getHeader(REQUEST_HEADER);

        if (this.validateHeader(authenticationHeader)) {

            logger.info("Header does not contain " + REQUEST_HEADER);

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

            return;

        }

        try {

            String jwtToken = this.extractJwtToken(authenticationHeader);

            String username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwtToken);

            if (this.isUserFound(username)) {

                logger.info("User {} was found from JWT filter", username);

                UserDetails userDetails = userRepository.loadUserByUsername(username);

                if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwtToken, userDetails)) {

                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = this.createAuthentication(userDetails, request);

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

                }

            }

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        } catch (ExpiredJwtException expiredJwtException) {

            handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(request, response, null, expiredJwtException);

        }

    }

    private @NotNull UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken createAuthentication(UserDetails userDetails, HttpServletRequest request) {

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        return authenticationToken;

    }

    public boolean isUserFound(String username) {

        return username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null;

    }

    public String extractJwtToken(@NotNull String authenticationHeader) {

        return authenticationHeader.substring(7);

    }

    public boolean validateHeader(String authenticationHeader) {

        return authenticationHeader == null || !authenticationHeader.startsWith(HEADER_PREFIX);

    }

}
```

And after setting up your `JwtAuthenticationFilter` class, we create an `ExceptionHandler` class for our custom JSON response

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

    private final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiExceptionHandler.class);

    public ApiExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;

    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getServerExceptionHandler(@NotNull Exception exception) {

        if (exception instanceof ExpiredJwtException) {

            ApiAuthenticationExceptionModel apiAuthenticationExceptionModel = new ApiAuthenticationExceptionModel(
                    HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(),
                    HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
                    "Authentication failed",
                    exception.getMessage(),
                    httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString(),
                    ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z"))
            );

            return new ResponseEntity<>(apiAuthenticationExceptionModel, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

        }

        logger.error("Something went wrong which is causing the application to fail: ", exception);

        ApiExceptionModel apiExceptionModel = new ApiExceptionModel(
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value(),
                exception.getMessage(),
                exception.getCause(),
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Z"))
        );

        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiExceptionModel, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }

}
```

And yes, you don't need to add any additional configuration in your Spring Security configuration class where SecurityFilters are situated.

This code can be extended to be even neater and clearer to accommodate more exception instances, making it a versatile solution for handling various JWT-related errors.

I hope this solution helps in most cases. Thank you for reading, and if you have any further questions or need additional assistance, please feel free to ask.